# Thread is still running or terminated exception in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

This is my code. I have a queue that gets images. Images are retrieved in a loop, this means that queueForImages.count always increases. So when I try to run this program sometimes it throws this exception and sometimes not. I mean ive exited the application and now ive run it again. It will show this exception sometimes and sometimes not.
I am new to threads. You can say I am a layman to know threads. So what am i missing? Do I have to dispose the thread or something before exiting application?

```
static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            Program obj = new Program();

            obj.handlerForImageBuffer();

        }

        void handlerForImageBuffer()

        {

            Bitmap mp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"path.bmp");

            Thread imageThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(processImages));

            for ( ; ; )

            {

                Console.WriteLine("Count: " + queueForImages.Count);

                if (queueForImages.Count == 10)

                {

                    queueFlag = true;                  

                    imageThread.Start();//Here comes the exception

                    Console.WriteLine("Q HAS 10 Elements");

                }
                queueForImages.Enqueue(Process(mp));//Same image is added for infinite times, just for the sake of testing.


            }

        }
```

Comment: need some more context in your code sample - how and when do you create the thread? Is a different thread adding items to the queue or is it the same thread?

Comment: What kind of exception is thrown? Do you call Start() multiple times on the same thread? In .NET Thread object cannot be reused. It means you have to create a new Thread in order to run it again.

Does the image queue has the same size on every application run? If not it would mean that sometimes you don't execute Start method multiple times so it doesn't throw any exception.

Comment: @ BrokenGlass edited my post. I have used just one thread. which needs to be invoked when the images count  reaches to 10. And dequeue these images.

Comment: @dzendras Exception is "Thread is already running or terminated,it cant be restarted"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> BrokenGlass edited my post. I have
>   used just one thread. which needs to
>   be invoked when the images count
>   reaches to 10. And dequeue these
>   images. –

And there's the problem - when you de-queue an image from the queue it's item count is reduced by one - so if there were 11 images before, now there are 10 and then your

```
  if (queueForImages.Count == 10)
```

will cause the Exception you see. to solve it combine the other answers offered here by @Danny Chen and @dzendras):

1. Use a `ConcurrentQueue` instead of
   whatever you are using now - regular
   queue is not thread safe.
2. Create new Thread instance each time
   the `Count == 10` because yes, this
   can occur multiple times since you add new images on the main thread, and remove them concurrently on a separate thread.

Answer (score 2):

You should provide the code of your *imageThread*. Currently I guess you are using an instance of [`Queue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) to store images, which is not thread-safe. If you are using C# 4.0 you can try [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) that guarantees tread-safety. If you are using an older version, you can implement your own `Queue<T>` derived from the built-in one, and override the Enqueue/Dequeue method to make it thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reuse the same thread object. It can run Start method only once. So if you want to runa method again, you have to create a new Thread object.

```
    void handlerForImageBuffer()

    {

        Bitmap mp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"path.bmp");

        for ( ; ; )

        {

            Console.WriteLine("Count: " + queueForImages.Count);

            if (queueForImages.Count == 10)

            {

                queueFlag = true;                  

                Thread imageThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(processImages));

                imageThread.Start();//Here comes the exception

                Console.WriteLine("Q HAS 10 Elements");

            }
            queueForImages.Enqueue(Process(mp));//Same image is added for infinite times, just for the sake of testing.


        }

    }
```